# why is my background image still distorting after adding needed styles

Tags: css, tailwind-css, background-image

I am trying to style a div by adding a background image. I have set h-screen, bg-no-repeat , bg-cover , bg-center. Yet its still not preserving the sharpness of the original picture.

I tried bg-no-repeat, bg-cover, bg-center and h-screen. I was expecting it to maintain its original sharpness and quality This is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/Oserebameh-Beckley/pen/JjmBzjX). How do i stop the bg image from losing its quality.

```css
#container {
  height: 100vh; 
  background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1162729319/photo/interior-of-a-fine-dining-indian-restaurant.jpg?b=1&s=170667a&w=0&k=20&c=puLKYH_iuK79S2_s27PhINO7rhvN9pej7gGbbH429Fg='); 
  background-size: cover; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: center; 
}
```

```html
<div id='container'> hello </div>
```

Comment: Have you purchased this? If so a much higher resolution image should be available. If not, maybe you aren’t licensed to use the image?

Comment: @Marcellus simply the image size is smaller. The css will not make it better. You have to use high quality image, so that it does not distort

Comment: The image you're using is a jpg, which is a bitmap image, which can't just be upscaled. Try to find the same image, but at a higher resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original size of the image you are using in your code pen is 509 x 331px (https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1162729319/photo/interior-of-a-fine-dining-indian-restaurant.jpg?b=1&s=170667a&w=0&k=20&c=puLKYH_iuK79S2_s27PhINO7rhvN9pej7gGbbH429Fg=) which is much smaller than the size it is displayed at in your codepen. You can't blow up a small image – it will look bad, or as you call it "distorted".

The simple solution: use a larger image.

Comment: "Why waste time say lot word when few word do trick?" - Kevin Malone

Comment: I don't waste time, I enjoy having it... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You use a different image, that is of higher resolution.